# How can I change input source in MacOS using Windows-style Shift + Command shortcut?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, shortcut, keybindings, input-source

I've been using Windows for most of my life and at this point I've developed a muscle memory to use **Shift + Alt** when I want to change language.

Using Macbook Air With macOS Big Sur (11.6) as my personal laptop and I was frustrated to learn that I can't simply go to System preferences and assign **Shift + Command** to change input source... from what I understood you need a 3rd party tool for that.

- I've tried Punto Switcher but it crashes from time to time on my M1 Mac and looks like it hasn't been updated in a while.
- Karabiner is confusing to setup and it caused me a kernel panic once.   =(

Is there another small (and preferably free) app that will allow me to assign key shortcuts to input source selection?

Comment: General Apple rule: You cannot use *only* modifier keys as a key command, you must have an alphanumeric [letter, number, symbol - or an f-key, which can be solo].  To use only modifiers would be intercepted before any other key command which used them & thus prevent the use of all of them.

Comment: @Tetsujin makes sense, but still it's kind of a bummer =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found an app called [CommandShift](https://github.com/VasylBaran/CommandShift), it allows to change language using "**<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>**, <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>, <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>" which is exactly what I need. It's free and gets the job done.